# Did Henry VIII's conversion from Catholicism set the stage for the readmission of Jews to England?

Tags: england, jews, henry-viii

I realize that 150 years passed between this conversion and Jews being invited back to England but I wonder if, as in Spain, it would not have happened for many years even after that? I also realize that there was antisemitism in Protestant countries, too, but it seems like, as in the case of Holland, there was more tolerance of religious minorities and in particular Jews there.

Comment: Very interesting idea. Especially given that Protestants took a much greater in the Old Testament than Catholics.

Comment: @felixgoldberg - is there a word missing?  Something doesn't scan right.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Yes, thanks! It should be "greater interest"

Comment: Recommend closing as a counterfactual / speculation ...